# Kafka Throughput producer performancetool in kafka acks = -1 vs acks = 1

Tags: apache-kafka

I am testing the Producer performance tool for Kafka 1.1.0 against 3 brokers with default configuration on AWS and I am running it with these commands

```
    compression.type = lz4    
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1  
    batch.size = 2000000   
    record size = 500 bytes   
    and acks = 0     
    num-records = 10000000   
    throughput = -1
```

when I run this I get an approximate throughput of 91 MB/sec

but when I change the acks to = -1 I get a throughput of 121 MB/sec

can someone explain if I am doing something wrong or shouldn't the throughput be higher if I don't have to wait for the replicas to ack the leader?

Comment: where are you getting the value for the `throughput `? maybe it is counting the replica part as well

Comment: @Paizo the -1 is the value so that the script does not try to hit a certain configured value for throughput, but the 91 and 121 is the output from the producer performer script that I run that comes with Kafka.